# Quando, por que e como utilizar a diretiva "use strict" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, use-strict

Nunca tinha visto antes a utilização desta diretiva, mas quase todos os plugins jQuery mais maduros a utilizam.

Gostaria de saber quando e como utilizá-la e qual a sua finalidade.

Comment: `use strict` força o Javascript a usar regras mais restritas pro seu código. Funciona bem se você sabe o que está fazendo. É uma boa prática sempre que você não tem que manter código ruim.

Comment: Seria algo como o HTML strict x transitional? Se você tiver um HTML bem feito e escrito você deve usar o strict, mas se você precisar de um pouco mais de flexibilidade em quebrar determinadas regras você usa o transitional. Conseguiria dar um exemplo onde um código JS funcionaria sem o uso dessa diretiva, mas não funcionaria utilizando a mesma?

Comment: Por exemplo, o `use strict` não permite que você crie variáveis globais acidentalmente. Por exemplo, se fizeres `a = 5` dentro de uma `function` antes de declarar `a` com `var`, sem o `use strict` você criará uma variável global `a`. Com o `use strict`, isso causará um erro, porque `a` não estava definida.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi: Na verdade, HTML strict e transitional fazem (praticamente) a mesma coisa do ponto de vista do Browser. A diferença que importa é entre documentos sem doctype (renderizados em *quirks mode*) vs documentos com algum doctype (renderizados segundo o padrão HTML). É por isso que o doctype recomendado hoje em dia é um simples `<!doctype html>`, sem número de versão.

Comment: Não sou  bem um especialista em HTML, @missingno. Mas pelo que vi o "use strict" também não afeta largamente o uso do JS sem a diretiva, acaba sendo quase a mesma coisa.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi: O "use strict" te ajuda a encontrar um *monte* de bugs. Seria tolice começar um projeto nove sem ele. Pra falar a verdade, a única razão que essa diretiva não é ativada por padrão nos browsers é que algumas das mudanças não são retrocompatíveis e iriam quebrar alguns sites existentes.

Comment: Estou usando ele agora e realmente apontou vários erros em javascripts que trouxemos de outros projetos. Foi mais fácil fazer na mão da forma correta.

Comment: Acho que é melhor usar o "use strict" em desenvolvimento e remover do código em produção.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Por que remover em produção? Os browsers antigos simplesmente ignoram a diretiva.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Como outros já disseram, o *strict mode* é um modo mais rigoroso de interpretação da linguagem, que proíbe certas práticas que sempre foram permitidas, mas não são recomendadas (como a criação de variáveis globais implícitas, já mencionadas em outras respostas). Como simplesmente proibir incondicionalmente esse tipo de prática quebraria códigos legados, foi decidido criar a diretiva `"use strict";` para ativar o modo estrito.

Existem duas maneiras de se utilizar o `"use strict"`:

- No topo do arquivo, a diretiva aplica o modo estrito para o arquivo todo.
- Como a primeira linha de código de uma função, a diretiva aplica o modo estrito somente dentro da função (incluindo outras funções eventualmente declaradas dentro dela).

O grande benefício de se o usar strict mode é reduzir a chance de existirem no código bugs difíceis de localizar (como um conflito de nome ao se criar uma global implícita, ou a existência de duas chaves iguais em objeto literal).

Preparei uma tradução livre e adaptada do [Anexo C da especificação da linguagem](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-strict-mode-of-ecmascript), que resume as restrições existentes no strict mode:

- Os identificadores `implements`, `interface`, `let`, `package`, `private`, `protected`, `public`, `static`, e `yield` são palavras reservadas quando utilizados no strict mode.
- Literais numéricos nunca são considerados octais, nem mesmo quando começam com zero. O mesmo vale para octais escapados em strings, como `'\012'` (que os browsers modernos nem suportam mais, mesmo fora do strict mode)
- Tentar atribuir um valor a uma variável que não existe no escopo atual não cria mais uma propriedade no objeto global (ou seja, não cria mais uma variável global). Em vez disso, lança uma exceção do tipo ReferenceError. Além disso, não é possível atribuir para propriedades que tenham o atributo {[[Writable]]:false}, nem para um *accessor* sem *setter* definido ({[[Set]]:undefined}), nem para propriedades de objetos cuja propriedade interna [[Extensible]] seja false. Em todos esses casos será lançado um TypeError.
- Não é possível redefinir `eval`, nem utilizá-lo com `++` ou `--`.
- Se você tentar acessar `arguments.caller` ou `arguments.callee` em uma função, será lançado um TypeError.
- Argumentos nomeados de funções não compartilham valores dinamicamente com as propriedades equivalentes indexadas numericamente. Por exemplo, em `function foo(bar) { arguments[0] = 10; }`, `bar` mantém o valor passado na chamada e não assume o valor `10`.
- O mesmo é válido no caso inverso: em `function foo(bar) { bar = 10; }`, `arguments[0]` mantém o valor passado na chamada e não assume o valor `10`.
- Se houver mais de uma propriedade com o mesmo nome em um objeto literal, um SyntaxError é lançado.
- Os identificadores "eval" e "arguments" não podem ser utilizados como nomes de parâmetros de funções que definam *getters* ou *setters* em objetos literais (mesmo que o código externo não esteja em strict mode, mas o corpo do getter/setter esteja).
- O `eval` em strict mode não pode instanciar variáveis ou funções no escopo de quem chama `eval`. O código passado ao `eval` irá criar um novo escopo, onde essas variáveis serão instanciadas.
- Em strict mode, não há coerção de `this` para objeto. Em casos onde `this` for `null` ou `undefined`, ele não será convertido para o objeto global. Por exemplo: em `function f(){ console.log(this) }; f();`, `this` é `undefined` em strict mode, e não o objeto global (em browsers, `window`). Além disso, se um valor primitivo for passado como `this`, ele não será convertido ao *wrapper* equivalente.
- O operador `delete` lança um SyntaxError quando utilizado em itens não deletáveis como variáveis, funções e argumentos. Por exemplo: `delete variavel`, `delete funcao` e `function(foo) { delete foo; }`.
- O operador `delete` lança um TypeError se a propriedade a ser deletada tiver o atributo { [[Configurable]]:false }.
- Se você tentar declarar uma variável com o nome de "eval" ou "arguments", será lançado um SyntaxError.
- O uso de `with` lança um SyntaxError.
- Numa cláusula `catch` não é possível utilizar "eval" ou "arguments" como nome da exceção; isso é um SyntaxError.
- Os identificadores "eval" e "arguments" não podem ser utilizados como nomes de parâmetros de funções; isso é um SyntaxError.
- Funções não podem ter múltiplos parâmetros com o mesmo nome; isso é um SyntaxError.
- É proibido às implementações estenderem o significado das propriedades "caller" e "arguments" de instâncias de funções para além do que consta da especificação.
- É um SyntaxError tentar utilizar "eval" ou "arguments" como nome de função ou parâmetro, assim como tentar forçar isso por meio do construtor `Function`.

Comment: Muito elucidativa a explicação, vale muito esse mais um por já citar adições da nova versão.

Comment: Obrigado, @PhilippeGioseffi. E vou tentar melhorar mais a resposta, acho um pouco confusa ainda porque fiz com pressa.

Answer (score 20):

Javascript é uma linguagem dinâmica e que não foi planejada pras dimensões em que é usada hoje em dia. Então ela tem alguns probleminhas. Por exemplo a declaração de variáveis, se você utilizar uma variável sem **var** antes, ela se tornará uma variável global, então você pode estar sobrescrevendo um valor que pode estar sendo usado por alguma outra função em algum outro lugar. Esse tipo de coisa causa erros que são muito difíceis de encontrar.

Esse tipo de comportamento é "natural" da linguagem e quebraria um monte de bibliotecas existentes caso fosse tirado da linguagem agora.

O "use strict" serve pra tentar amenizar esses problemas, navegadores que reconhecem essa diretiva vão emitir erros quando encontram código que é javascript válido mas que é potencialmente problemático, como o caso de usar variáveis sem declarar com **var**. Navegadores antigos que não reconhecem simplesmente ignoram a diretiva.

E como o "use strict" pode ser usado em blocos de código, você pode utilizar dentro das suas novas funções sem precisar refatorar todas suas bibliotecas antigas.

Exemplo de uso:

```
y = 2;//funciona sem problemas porque esta fora do bloco
function foo() {
  "use strict";
  x = 1;//emite erro em navegadores suportados
}
```

Referência: http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/

Answer (score 7):

'use strict' é usado para expor as exceções do seu código javascript, vendo os erros mais detalhadamente

Exemplo

```
    function isStrictMode(){
      return !this;
    } 
    //retorna falso, uma vez que "this" se refere ao objeto global e '!this' se torna falso

    function isStrictMode(){   
      "use strict";
       return !this;
   } 
  //retorna verdadeiro, pois no modo estrito, a palavra-chave "this" não se refere ao objeto global, ao contrário JS tradicionais. Então, aqui, "this" é nulo e '!this' se torna verdade.
```

Comment: Poderia exemplificar?

Comment: O link é bom, inclusive inclui link para dizer quais browsers suportam ou não essa diretiva. Não poderei usar aqui, pois sou obrigado a escrever código que rode nos IEs 7 e 8 que não suportam esta diretiva.

Comment: Embora seja uma resposta interessante, ela cobre muito pouco do que a diretiva faz.

Comment: @utluiz pelo que vi quase todo mundo exemplifica da mesma maneira, falando sobre variáveis globais e não globais através da utilização da declaração da variável com **var**.

Comment: @Philippe Exemplificar é uma coisa. Entretanto, a resposta não diz, por exemplo, que o modo `scrict` afeta diretamente o modo como o script é executado pela *engine*. Não estou dizendo que a resposta está ruim ou errada, apenas incompleta.

Comment: É, algumas respostas abaixo falam sobre isso, incluindo a informação que alguns códigos podem parar de funcionar. Uma colocação que achei bem interessante foi a de que browsers mais antigos ignoram a diretiva sem causar maiores problemas. Talvez fosse legal compilar algumas respostas junto à pergunta e criar uma Wiki. O que acha?

Answer (score 5):

O JavaScript foi originalmente desenhado para ser fácil de aprender por programadores inexperientes. E portanto fizeram do JavaScript uma linguagem em que é permitido fazer todo o tipo de asneiras - o compilador raramente se queixa. Penso que toda a gente já percebeu que é preferível que o compilador nos avise dos erros que cometemos, em vez de silenciosamente ignorar os erros. O "strict mode" muda semântica do JavaScript para um modo mais estrito, em que situações de provável erro são rejeitas pelo compilador. Exemplo:

```js
var length = 1;
...
lenght = 2;  // "length" mal escrito - em JavaScript normal
             // uma nova variável global chamada "lenght" é
             // criada
```

```js
'use strict';
var length = 1;
...
lenght = 2;  // "length" mal escrito - em "strict mode" uma
             // excepção é lançada
```

É importante frisar que o "strict mode" muda a semântica do programa. Um programa que funcionava correctamente sem "strict mode", pode deixar de funcionar com o "strict mode" activo. Para além disso o "strict mode" não é suportado por todos os browsers, e portanto é necessário ter cuidado pois código que funciona correctamente com o "strict mode" activo, pode não funcionar em browsers que não suportam o "strict mode".

Answer (score 3):

O Caio Gondim escreveu um artigo a respeito muito bom no Loop Infinito que diz o seguinte:

> O strict mode é uma nova feature do ECMAScript 5 que permite fazer que o código JavaScript rode em um modo mais rigoroso. Neste modo, a engine de JavaScript tem seu comportamento modificado, gerando erros que antes eram silenciados e, até mesmo, proibindo o uso de certas partes da linguagem que são tidas como problemáticas, nos forçando assim a escrever um código de melhor qualidade e ajudando a capturar bugs mais precocemente.

Lá no artigo ele também exemplifica como utilizar. Sugiro dar uma olhada.

http://loopinfinito.com.br/2013/07/16/javascript-strict-mode/

Answer (score 3):

O "use strict" é uma diretiva em que você está diz para o compilador não permitir que você cometa falhas no seu código que não são consideradas erros pelo interpretador, porém podem te causar dores de cabeça. Por exemplo, o Javascript te permite utilizar uma variável sem ser declarada, ou redefinir a variável **arguments** dentro de funções:

O código abaixo é considerado válido sem o uso da diretiva "use strict":

```
function f() {
  var arguments = [];
}

x = 0;
```

Porém, se utilizado "use strict":

```
"use strict";

function f() {
  var arguments = []; // SyntaxError: Variable name may not be eval or arguments in strict mode
}

x = 0; // ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

Comment: Me ajudou à achar a diferença do modo estrito e do modo não-estrito... Obrigado!