# Strict Mode em JavaScript funciona em frameworks?

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando JavaScript e me deparei com o Strict Mode (`use strict`). Eu gostaria de saber se ele funciona com as *frameworks* de JavaScript se eu colocar este comando em um arquivo `.js`, ou se só funciona com JavaScript puro? Por ser suportado somente pelas ultimas versões de alguns navegadores, atualmente é viável usá-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende do caso. Mas os *frameworks* mais modernos costumam ser compatíveis e até fazem uso extensivo deste modo. Os mais antigos começaram se adaptar mas tem que analisar caso a caso. jQuery e Angular são exemplos que funcionam bem, imagino que vale o mesmo para React, Vue, etc.

Tem que testar e ver, mas a chance de funcionar é grande, afinal, seu uso é uma "boa prática" em muitas situações.

[Entendendo seu uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2746/101).

Comment: Seria uma boa ideia iniciar o desenvolvimento de um projeto usando está diretiva, sabendo que navegadores antigos a ignoram? Não geraria problemas inesperados?

Comment: Em geral sim. O fato de ser ignorado não é um problema no funcionamento do *script* porque só vai permitir coisas que provavelmente não está no seu código que deve ter sido testado com o modo habilitado. Pode se tornar um problema quando começa misturar código que está bem adaptado ao modo e código não adaptado. Em geral códigos desses *frameworks* são escritos pensando nisto. E mesmo quando não acontece, será raro, mas não impossível,causar algum problema com outros códigos.Só aconteceria se um trecho que não está *strict* exija que outro não esteja para funcionar.Só código mal feito faz isto

Comment: Entendi obrigado!