# Como concatenar propriedades de objetos com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Possuo dois objetos no JavaScript, com os seguintes dados:

```
const objeto1 = {
    prop1: 'a', 
    prop2: 'b', 
    prop3: 'c'
}
const objeto2 = {
    prop4: 'd', 
    prop5: 'e', 
    prop6: 'f'
}
```

Eu queria pegar essas propriedades todas e unir em um mesmo objeto, e cheguei nisso através do seguinte código:

```
const objeto3 = objeto1;
objeto3.prop4 = objeto2.prop4;
objeto3.prop5 = objeto2.prop5;
objeto3.prop6 = objeto2.prop6;
```

Mas eu vi que, em `arrays`, eu posso fazer usando [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), e pensei que agora está fácil, mas se o objeto tivesse mais propriedades, me causaria problemas. Existe uma forma de concatenar esses dois objetos de forma simplificada?

Comment: Tu consegue isso utilizando o `Array.prototype.concat()`

Comment: tentei, mas me rendeu esse erro: `Uncaught TypeError: objeto1.concat is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:25`

Comment: Pode fornecer um [mcve] de como fez essa concatenação que gerou erro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existem diversas formas de se fazer isso. Abaixo listarei três casos diferentes.

### Utilizar a sintaxe de espalhamento (*spread operator*)

Se você estiver em um ambiente que a [suporte](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_spread_spread_in_object_literals), você pode usar a [sintaxe de espalhamento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Espalhamento_em_objetos_literais), também conhecida como *spread operator*, em objetos literais. Funciona assim:

```js
const obj1 = { foo: 'A', bar: 'B' };
const obj2 = { baz: 'C' /* ... */ };

const newObj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };

console.log(newObj);
```

Basicamente, no exemplo acima, estamos criando um novo objeto, `newObj`, através da sintaxe de espalhamento. Basicamente, com isso:

```js
   { ...obj1, ...obj2 }
// ↑
// Entenda isso como a criação de um novo objeto. Por isso `obj1` e `obj2` não
// são alterados.
```

Estamos programando a criação de um **novo objeto**, cujas propriedades derivar-se-ão do espalhamento de `obj1` e `obj2`. Nesse caso, `obj1` e `obj2` *não* terão suas propriedades modificadas, já que estamos criando uma nova literal.

Note que você pode criar um objeto com as propriedades espalhadas e novas propriedades também. Assim:

```js
const oldObj = {
  foo: 'A'
};

const newObj = {
  ...oldObj,
  bar: 'B',
  baz: 'C' 
};

console.log(newObj);
```

### `Object.assign`

Você também pode utilizar o [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), que é um pouco mais suportado que a sintaxe de espalhamento. Assim:

```js
const obj1 = { foo: 'A', bar: 'B' };
const obj2 = { baz: 'C' /* ... */ };

const newObj = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);

console.log(newObj);
```

Note que no método `assign`, eu coloquei uma nova literal de objeto no primeiro argumento. Fiz isso porque esse método irá mutar a referência que você passar no primeiro argumento:

```js
const obj1 = { foo: 'A', bar: 'B' };
const obj2 = { baz: 'C' /* ... */ };

Object.assign(obj1, obj2);

console.log('Objeto 1', obj1);
console.log('Objeto 1', obj2);
```

A própria [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Espalhamento_em_objetos_literais) do `Object.assign` nomeia o primeiro argumento como `target`. Isso porque, conforme expliquei acima, a referência que você passar para ele será alterada. Por isso é útil passar um novo objeto se você não quiser que isso aconteça.

### Outras implementações (para ambientes *antigos*)

Se você quiser dar suporte a ambientes que não tenham esses novos recursos, introduzidos em *especificações recentes* do ECMAScript, ainda há formas (um pouco menos triviais) de fazer isso. Uma delas é usar um laço [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), que itera sobre as propriedades enumeradas de um objeto. Então, pode fazer algo assim:

```js
// Irá retornar um **novo** objeto, a partir da união dos argumentos.
function merge() {
  'use strict';

  // Note que criamos um novo objeto. Assim nenhum objeto
  // passado será alterado. :)
  var newObj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    // `arguments`:
    var currentObj = arguments[i];

    for (var key in currentObj) {
      // `hasOwnProperty`:
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(currentObj, key)) {
        newObj[key] = currentObj[key];
      }
    }
  }

  return newObj;
}

var obj1 = { foo: 'A', bar: 'B' };
var obj2 = { baz: 'C' };
var obj3 = { qux: 'D' };

var newObj = merge(obj1, obj2, obj3);

console.log(newObj);
```

A implementação anterior da função `merge` usa alguns recursos da linguagem que são muito pouco usados:

- O [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) foi usado, já que a função `merge` foi implementada visando aceitar múltiplos argumentos (como `merge(a, b, c, d, ... n)`). Desse modo, utilizei `arguments`, já que recursos modernos como o *spread operator*, que são usados para fazer isso em ambientes que suportam novas especificações do ECMAScript, não estão disponíveis.
- O método [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) foi utilizada para garantir que somente propriedades do objeto passado sejam unidas. Isso excluirá propriedades herdadas pelo `prototype`.
- A declaração [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) foi usada, já que `let` e `const` não estariam disponíveis nesse ambiente hipotético. A diretiva [`'use strict'`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2746/quando-por-que-e-como-utilizar-a-diretiva-use-strict-em-javascript) também foi utilizada nesse sentido.

Comment: Por que o negativo? T_T

Comment: Também gostaria de saber?

Comment: Uma resposta excelente com poucos votos é inacreditável

Comment: @LuizFelipe deve ser perseguição por alguma pergunta que tenha fechado. Já passei por isso.

Comment: Provavelmente. É a triste realidade que eventualmente temos que enfrentar por aqui. :P