# Qual é a definição de delete em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, objetos, operadores, delete

Deparei-me com uma instrução em que o `delete` representa um tipo em JavaScript. Pelo menos foi o que eu entendi.

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês pois não encontrei nenhuma referencia na internet.

```
if (MvL.object.hasValue(domain.cpf) || MvL.object.hasValue(domain.cnpj)) {
  delete domain.nome_cliente;
  delete domain.cod_cgl;
  delete domain.uf;
}
```

Comment: Referências na intenet tem um monte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete. Aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) não é um tipo, mas sim um *operador* que remove uma propriedade de um objeto. No entanto, só irá funcionar em propriedades que possuam o [*atributo de propriedade*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296) `[[Configurable]]` definido como `true`. Veja:

```js
const obj = {};
obj.name = 'Luiz';
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'lastName', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false // Não irá permitir que deletemos a propriedade `lastName`.
});

console.log(obj); 
delete obj.name;
delete obj.lastName;
console.log(obj);
```

No modo normal do JavaScript, se você tentar deletar uma propriedade não configurável, `false` será retornado. No entanto, se você estiver no [modo estrito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2746/quando-por-que-e-como-utilizar-a-diretiva-use-strict-em-javascript), um erro será lançado:

```js
'use strict';

const obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'lastName', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false
});

delete obj.lastName; // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot delete property 'lastName'
```

Esse operador irá retornar `true` em todos os casos, exceto quando você tentar remover uma propriedade não configurável sem estar no modo estrito – já vimos que, nesse último caso, um erro é lançado.

Se, mesmo no modo estrito, você quiser receber um booleano `false` se não tiver conseguido deletar a propriedade, você pode usar o método [`Reflect.deleteProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/deleteProperty), introduzido no ECMAScript 2015 (ES6):

```js
'use strict';

const obj = {};
obj.name = 'Luiz';
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'lastName', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false
});

console.log(obj); 
console.log(Reflect.deleteProperty(obj, 'name')); // true
console.log(Reflect.deleteProperty(obj, 'lastName')); // false
console.log(obj);
```

Vale dizer que tanto `delete` quanto `Reflect.deleteProperty` retornarão `true` mesmo se a propriedade que você tentar deletar não existir.

Para aprofundar sobre o operador `delete`, vale ler o artigo "[Understanding delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)". Detalhes mais avançados e algoritmo encontram-se na [especificação](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-delete-operator).

Answer (score 0):

Dá uma olhada neste exemplo:

```js
var person = {
    name: "Harry",
    age: 16,
    gender: "Male"
};

// Deleta a propriedade completamente
delete person.age;
alert(person.age); // Saida: undefined
console.log(person); // Saida: {name: "Harry", gender: "Male"}

// Definindo propriedade como undefined
person.gender = undefined;
alert(person.gender); // Saida: undefined
console.log(person); // Saida: {name: "Harry", gender: undefined}
```

O `delete` remove a propriedade do objeto, caso você precise apenas alterar o valor da propriedade o exemplo também mostra como alterar o valor.