# Variável global retorna undefined ao usar this em Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, escopo-de-variáveis, this

Estou estudando sobre a variável especial `this` e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Ao executar a função abaixo no Node.js (versão 12.18.3) o resultado é `undefined` e só retorna `2` se eu criar uma variável global (removendo o `var`), mas ao executar este mesmo código no navegador (Google Chrome), o resultado é `2`, como esperado...

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this.a);
}

var a = 2;

foo(); // 2
```

No browser, o código acima imprime `2`. No Node.js, a saída é `undefined`.

Não entendi esse comportamento, visto que qualquer variável declarada no escopo global já faz parte das propriedades do objeto global, certo?

Não creio que exista relação com o [modo estrito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2746/69296), haja vista que, se este estiver habilitado, ao rodar o código acima (no browser e no Node.js), um erro é lançado:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
> ```

Comment: O nodejs utiliza a o modo `strict` do javascript. Isso trás algumas mudanças relacionadas a otimização do código.

Comment: @Danizavtz: resposta? :)

Comment: Pode mandar @Sergio não vou poder

Comment: Posso complementar com uma resposta logo abaixo, se ficar faltando alguma coisa pra explicar

Comment: o strict mode vem habilitado por padrão? se sim, não era pra dar erro quando ele declara a variável global (sem o var)?

Answer (score 8):

Vamos por partes...

---

#### `this` dentro da função

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context), no Node, o `this` dentro da função é igual ao objeto global:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this === global); // true
}

foo();
```

Já no browser, `this` é igual a `window`:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this === window); // true
}

foo();
```

---

#### Com e sem `var`

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), ao criar uma variável com `var` no Node fora de uma função (no *top-level* do módulo), ela é local ao módulo, mas não é global.

Segundo a [documentação do Node](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

> *The top-level scope is not the global scope; `var something` inside a Node.js module will be local to that module.*

Ou seja, `var a` não está colocando a variável no escopo global:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(a); // 2
  console.log(this.a); // undefined
}

var a = 2;
console.log(global.a); // undefined
foo();
```

Veja que `global.a` é `undefined` (pois a variável `a` é local ao módulo, e não global). E como dentro da função, `this` é igual a `global`, então `this.a` é `undefined`.

Já sem o `var`, a variável passa a ser global, e por isso dá para acessá-la dentro da função com `this.a`:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(a); // 2
  console.log(this.a); // 2
}

a = 2;
console.log(global.a); // 2
foo();
```

---

Mas no browser, como `this` é igual a `window` (que por sua vez é onde vão parar as variáveis globais, com ou sem `var`), então `this.a` funciona em ambos os casos.

Com `var`:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(a); // 2
  console.log(this.a); // 2
}

var a = 2; // com var
console.log(window.a); // 2
foo();
```

E sem `var`:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(a); // 2
  console.log(this.a); // 2
}

a = 2; // sem var
console.log(window.a); // 2
foo();
```

Comment: Até escrever uma resposta para complementar com um detalhe, mas vou deixar aqui mesmo já que é algo muito pequeno e ia acabar repetindo muita coisa boa que já tem aqui. O Node.js trata o "top-level" de cada arquivo com escopo "de módulo" e não global por conta de algo chamado "[module wrapping](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper)", que é basicamente colocar uma IIFE em volta de cada módulo. Ou seja, não é nada muito "low-level" que o Node.js faz para mudar o comportamento "normal". :-)

Answer (score 7):

Quero contribuir na pergunta e vou, talvez, acrescentar na respota do @hkotsubo.

Vou começar a minha resposta com uma pergunta:

*Por que o código abaixo requer mais tempo pra ser executado no navegador Chrome do que em um arquivo executado pelo NodeJS, se ambos usam o V8?*

```js
console.time('loop');

for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 1) {
  // faz nada..
}

console.timeEnd('loop');
```

### A questão do `var` nos navegadores

```html
<script>
  var test = 'teste';
</script>
```

Declarar um variável com `var` fora do escopo de uma funcão (como exemplo acima), **faz com que ela seja atribuida ao objeto global**. É realizado um `bind` da variável ao objeto global (`window`) e esse processo é custoso em termos de execução do código no navegador. Já nos da uma dica do porque no seu código, o `this.a` nos retorna `2` no navegador, pois o `var a = 2;` foi declarado fora do escopo de funcão.

*Já nos dar uma pista para responder a pergunta que fiz lá no começo. Ficar atribuindo repetidamente o `i` ao objeto global window (***que é extremamente populado***) a cada iteração do loop, ***afeta a performance de execução***.*

### A questão do `var` no NodeJS

Arquivo index.js:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this.teste);
}

var teste = 'teste';

foo(); // undefined
```

Quando NodeJS foi desenvolvido, a questão do `var` foi analisado para que os problemas dele no navegador não se repita no ambiente NodeJS. Vamos concordar que ficar criando funções em cada arquivo no Node pra tratar o `var` da mesma forma que fazemos em script de navegadores ficaria algo chato. Então o comportamento do Node se difere aí.

No Nodejs, declarar qualquer variável fora do escopo de qualquer função, a vincula apenas ao próprio escopo do módulo (não ao objeto global). Cada arquivo tem seu próprio escopo, isto foi pensado para evitar que uma variável extrapole o escopo de um arquivo. Imagine debugar se tivesse o problema de extrapolação de escopo de variáveis de arquivos no Node. Esse comportamento explica o porque do seu código ao se executado no Node, ele retorna `undefined`, pois o Node não faz o `bind` da variável `var a = 2;` ao objeto global (`global`), ele deixa ela atribuída ao escopo do próprio arquivo, logo `this.a` é igual `global.a` que é `undefined`.

Pra facilitar o entendimento, imagine que o Node trata cada arquivo como uma função auto contida e que cada variável declarada com `var`, `let` ou `const` fica atribuida a o escopo dessa função.

*Já nos dar a pista final para responder a pergunta que fiz lá no inicio. Como o Node vai ficar atribuindo o `i` ao escopo do próprio arquivo (***que é pouco populoso***), fica mais fácil e rápido a repetida atribuição do `i`, o que resulta em ***melhor performance de execução*** comparada a performance do navegador.*

---

#### *Observação*:

Se você declarar uma variável em um arquivo sem usar a palavra-chave `var` e, em seguida, atribuir um valor a ela, o objeto global definirá uma propriedade para essa variável. Esse processo essencialmente o transforma em uma **variável acessível globalmente**. Eu fortemente não aconselho o uso desse método, pois não é a maneira adequada de criar variáveis globais.

Também é importante observar que se você definir a diretiva `'use strict'` (que não vem ativada por padrão), o Node desabilitará os globais implícitos e você provavelmente terminará com um erro no tempo de execução.

---

### Resumindo

Ficou entendido o porque do comportamento distindo em ambos ambientes?

No browser:

- `var` fora de escopo de função é atribuida ao objeto `window`.

No NodeJS:

- Cada arquivo é tratado como módulo separado (escopo próprio de arquivo)
- Objeto `global` está disponível em todos os arquivos, mas por padrão `var` não é atribuido a este objeto
- Enquanto nos navegadores o escopo global é o objeto `window`, no nodeJS o escopo global de um módulo é o próprio módulo, então, quando você define uma variável no escopo global do seu módulo Node.js, ela será local para este módulo.

### Respondendo minha pergunta

A diferença no processo de atribuir o `i` ao objeto global em cada ambiente de execução (`window` no browser e próprio escopo do arquivo no Node) resulta em performance diferente.

Nos meus testes, foram os seguintes resultados (saídas no console):

- NodeJS:

```bsh
  loop: 2.669ms
```

- Browser:

```bsh
  loop: 4.543212890625 ms
```

Execute o script aqui e veja o resultado para o browser.

```js
console.time('loop');

for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 1) {
  // faz nada..
}

console.timeEnd('loop');
```

Depois execute este mesmo script em NodeJS em um arquivo e veja a diferença dos resultados.

### Referências:

- [Node.js - Knowing the Global Objects](https://blog.greenroots.info/nodejs-knowing-the-global-objects-cjv7shtzb004b67s1u5cnwmku)
- [Using Global Variables in Node.js](https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20declare%20a%20variable,into%20a%20globally%20accessible%20variable.)
- [The module wrapper](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper)

---

### Curiosidade

Ao entrar no modo **REPL** do Node, ele não aplica a questão de escopo de arquivo, então o comportamento esperado se assemelha ao comportamento dos navegadores.

```
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v12.19.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> function foo() {
...   console.log(this.teste);
... }
undefined
> 
> var teste = 'teste';
undefined
> 
> foo(); // teste
teste
undefined
>
```

---