# Por que o Node.js aceita atribuição de valores com o identificador "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, característica-linguagem, objetos, undefined

Estava eu realizando um quiz sobre Node.js até que me deparei com a seguinte questão:

> Qual mensagem irá aparecer no terminal para o seguinte código executado pelo Node.js:
>
> Código (repare que ele executa fora de escopo de função):
>
> ```js
> 'use strict';
>
> var undefined = { foo: 'bar' };
> console.log(undefined);
> ```
>
> Alternativas:
>
> 1. `foo`
> 2. `undefined`
> 3. `TypeError`
> 4. `{ foo: 'bar' }`

A resposta correta é o item 4.

Acontece que o mesmo código não é valido se executado em navegadores:

```js
'use strict';

var undefined = { foo: 'bar' };
console.log(undefined);
```

Temos o erro `TypeError` se executarmos o código acima. Eu estava com essa resposta em mente, mas o comportamento difere do Node.js.

- Por quê?
- O que causou o Node.js aceitar atribuição de valor para o `undefined` fora de escopo de função, se o mesmo não é possível nos navegadores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Por que o Node.js aceita atribuição de valores para o “undefined”?

Não é só o Node.js. Como o `undefined` não é uma [palavra-chave da linguagem](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words), pode ser utilizado como um identificador, de modo que pode atuar como nome de propriedade, variável, etc. Veja:

```js
function foo() {
  const undefined = 5;
  return typeof undefined;
}

const myObj = {
  undefined: true
};

console.log(foo()); //=> number
console.log(myObj); //=> { undefined: true }
```

Não sei porque alguém faria isso, mas é totalmente válido utilizar `undefined` como um identificador no JavaScript. Ao contrário de `null`, por exemplo, que já é uma palavra-chave.

---

## Então por que não consigo atribuir um valor à `undefined` no escopo global?

Na verdade, você pode. Veja:

```js
var undefined = 1;
undefined = 2;

console.log(undefined); //=> undefined
```

Note que a atribuição foi, de fato, feita (no escopo global). No entanto, ao contrário dos exemplos anteriores, o conteúdo sob o nome `undefined` não foi alterado.

A atribuição só é impedida em contexto estrito de avaliação (utilizando a diretiva [`"use strict"`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2746/69296) ou em módulos ECMAScript, ESM). Veja:

```js
'use strict';

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'undefined' of object '#<Window>'
var undefined = 1; // utilizando var

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'undefined' of object '#<Window>'
undefined = 1; // sem palavra-chave de declaração
```

#### Por que isso ocorre?

Quando se define uma variável no escopo global sem utilizar uma palavra-chave de declaração **ou** utilizando `var` (e em modo de execução não estrito), ocorre automaticamente a atribuição do valor ao objeto global `globalThis`. Veja:

```js
// Sem palavra-chave de declaração:
var1 = 1;

// Utilizando `var`:
var var2 = 2;

// Utilizando `let` (mesmo comportamento se utilizar `const`,
// que têm um comportamento diferente).
let var3 = 3;

console.log(var1, globalThis.var1); //=> 1 1
console.log(var2, globalThis.var2); //=> 1 2
console.log(var3, globalThis.var3); //=> 3 undefined
```

E o problema com isso é que já existe uma propriedade qualificada por `undefined` no objeto global. Vejamos seu **[descritor de propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296)**:

```js
console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(globalThis, 'undefined')
);
```

Repare que a propriedade `undefined`, no objeto global, possui o atributo `[[Writable]]` definido como `false`. É por isso que, no modo estrito, quando tentamos alterar essa propriedade (o que ocorre implicitamente mediante "declaração" no escopo global), lança-se um `TypeError`. No modo estrito, um `TypeError` é lançado para tentativa de modificação do valor de uma propriedade definida com atributo `[[Writable]]` falso.

#### Por que no Node.js isso não ocorre?

Código Node.js avaliado sob CommonJS é envolvido por um [*module wrapper*](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) para proteger atribuições no *top-level* de "contaminarem" o escopo global.

Portanto, todo código *top-level* em Node.js não é, na prática, global, haja vista que se encontra envolvido em uma IIFE. Então o identificador `undefined`, sem a ligação implícita ao objeto global no escopo global, encontra-se "disponível" para uso.

Módulos em Node.js CommonJS nada mais passam do que código envolvido em uma função, então de nada diferem do primeiro exemplo que demonstrei nesta resposta.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta é até bem simples...

> The module wrapper

### Relembrando...

O `undefined` é uma propriedade do objeto `global`, ou seja, é uma variável no escopo global. O valor inicial de u`ndefined` é o valor primitivo `undefined`.

Nos browsers modernos, a especificação ECMAScript 5 define que o `undefined` é uma propriedade não configurável e somente leitura. Mesmo quando esse não for o caso, evite sobrescrevê-lo.

Uma vez que `undefined` [não é uma palavra reservada](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#keywords), ele pode ser usado como um identificador (nome de variável) em qualquer escopo que **não seja o escopo global**.

<sup>[fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)</sup>

Exemplo de código executando **fora do escopo global**:

```js
;// escreve no console "foo string"
(function () {
  var undefined = 'foo'
  console.log(undefined, typeof undefined)
})()

// escreve no console "foo string"
;(function (undefined) {
  console.log(undefined, typeof undefined)
})('foo')
```

### Tá, mas e no Node.js?

É ai que entra o *module wrapper*. Cada arquivo JS (módulo) que será executado pelo Node.js, sofre, antes de ser executado, um "empacotamento" de escopo que é causado por uma função. Isso, além de causar um escopo fechado no módulo, faz com que **este arquivo não seja executado no escopo global**. Este comportamento também explica a questão do `this` no Node.js, que foi abordada [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/464600/95771)...

> No Nodejs, declarar qualquer variável fora do escopo de qualquer função, a vincula apenas ao próprio escopo do módulo (não ao objeto global). Cada arquivo tem seu próprio escopo, isto foi pensado para evitar que uma variável extrapole o escopo de um arquivo...

Então, ao executar o código da pergunta no Node.js, a função fica desta forma "por baixo dos panos" por causa do *module wrapper*:

```js
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  'use strict'

  var undefined = { foo: 'bar' }

  console.log(undefined)
})
```

Se você simular esta execução no navegador, não teremos erro:

```js
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  'use strict'

  var undefined = { foo: 'bar' }

  console.log(undefined)
})()
```

### Concluindo

Por mais que você não use uma função no seu arquivo, o Node.js empacota todo seu código dentro de uma função. Isso por questões características da plataform, com intuito de manter comportamento de algumas coisas:

- Ele mantém as variáveis *top-level* (definidas com `var`, `const` ou `let`) com escopo no módulo em vez do objeto global, permitindo assim a trabalhar com atributos que serão privados dentro de cada arquivo, onde esses atributos podem somente serem acessados por funções dentro do próprio arquivo.
- Atributos do arquivo só serão acessados por outros arquivos se estes forem explicitamente exportados.
- Isso ajuda a fornecer algumas variáveis de aparência global que são realmente específicas para o módulo, como:

  - Os objetos `module` e `exports` que o implementador pode usar para exportar valores do módulo.
  - As variáveis de conveniência `__filename` e `__dirname`, contendo o nome de arquivo absoluto do módulo e o caminho do diretório.

---

**OBS**:

A explicação da conclusão acima é valida se considerar o `type` como `commonjs`. No caso do tipo `module`, os parâmetros não são aplicáveis para o *module wrapper*.

**OBS 2**:

O mesmo comportamento vale para o `NaN`, pois o mesmo também é uma propriedade do objeto global e não é uma *keyword* do JS:

```js
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  'use strict'

  var NaN = { foo: 'bar' }

  console.log(NaN)
})()
```

No modo estrito:

```js
'use strict';

var NaN = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

console.log(NaN)
```

Fora do modo estrito:

```js
var NaN = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

console.log(NaN)
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(globalThis, 'NaN'))
```

Comment: Boa resposta (e pergunta)! Mas e essa bizarrice de colocar ponto e vírgula antes da IIFE? Não é melhor simplesmente usar o ponto e vírgula ao final de cada declaração onde esperado? :D

Comment: @LuizFelipe kkkkkkkkkk, só tenho uma explicacao para isso: `SHIFT` + `ALT` + `F`.