# Como funciona e quais são as regras do contexto de execução dos ECMAScript 6 modules (ESM)?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, módulo-ecmascript

Desde o ECMAScript 5, o JavaScript possui, tradicionalmente, dois contextos de execução:

- *Sloopy mode* (nome informal utilizado para se referir modo habilitado por padrão na maioria dos contextos de execução).
- *Strict mode*, habilitado explicitamente através da diretiva `"use strict"` ou automaticamente em alguns contextos da linguagem, como [blocos de classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class#description).

A habilitação do modo estrito implica algumas mudanças sutis no modo como a linguagem funciona. Esse comportamento é melhor explicado nesta [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2746/69296).

A partir do ES6, foram introduzidos os *ECMAScript Modules*, que, até onde sei, implicam na existência de um terceiro contexto de execução, com algumas regras exclusivas a códigos executados em *ES modules*.

- Onde o contexto de execução de módulos é habilitado?
- Quais são as suas regras?

  - O que muda em relação ao já existente modo estrito?