# Como usar parâmetros explicitamente ao chamar funções quando o "use strict" está ativado?

Tags: javascript

Nos meus scripts em javascript, gosto de usar a `user strict` no topo do arquivo, por que li nessa [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2746/quando-por-que-e-como-utilizar-a-diretiva-use-strict-em-javascript) que se trata de uma boa prática. Segundo uma das respostas na referida questão:

> O grande benefício de se o usar strict mode é reduzir a chance de existirem no código bugs difíceis de localizar.

Ocorre que notei hoje que essa prática causa um problema quando uso parâmetros explicitamente em uma chamada de função. Por exemplo, sem usar `user strict`, esse código funciona perfeitamente:

```js
const contract = (author, socialSecurity,father, mother, year)=> {
    const statement = `I, ${author}, under the social security ${socialSecurity}, and son of ${father} and ${mother}, declare that all land after the waterfall and before the Mr. Whitaker's mills belongs to my family since ${year}.`;

    return statement;
}

console.log(contract(author="John Smith", socialSecurity=98989, father = "Johan Smith Bay", mother = "Mary Smith", year=1845))
```

Mas quando uso `user strict` esse código falha e retorna o erro:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable author
```

Como se ao fazer `contract(author="John Smith", ...` eu estivesse tentando declarar a variável `author`.

Existe uma forma de continuar usando `use strict`e declarar explicitamente o nome dos parâmetros da função ao chamá-la?

Comment: Você está passando os parâmetros na ordem. No javascript, não tem como assinalar o nome da propriedade na chamada, somente pela ordem mesmo. Se você der um `console.log(foo="bar")` a saída será `bar` e nem por isso `foo` existiu em algum momento.

Comment: Quem está negativando a pergunta poderia justificar o motivo dos negativos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe sintaxe de parâmetros nomeados em JavaScript.

## *Assignment expressions*

Isto (ênfase na última linha):

```js
function foo(a, b) {
  console.log(`a is ${a}, b is ${b}`);
}

foo(a=1, b=2);
```

Não é um exemplo de aplicação com argumentos nomeados. O que de fato pode ser confirmado se a ordem de aplicação for invertida. Se executar `foo(b=2, a=1);`, a saída será diferente.

O que ocorre, por exemplo, em `a = 1` chama-se *assignment expression* ou, em Português, expressão de atribuição.

Basicamente, em JavaScript, quando se faz:

```
let a; // Declaração da variável (isto é um statement)
a = 5; // Atribuição de variável (tudo antes do ponto e vírgula é uma expressão)
```

Em `a = 5`, tem-se uma atribuição de `5` à variável `a`. Essa atribuição é uma expressão, e não uma declaração. Por conta disso, se avaliar somente `a = 5` (sem o ponto e vírgula, que a converte para um *expression statement*) terá como resultado `5`, isto é, o valor que foi atribuído é retornado. Isso de fato está [documentado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) e, claro, especificado.

E só para confirmar, fornecendo  `foo(a=1, b=2);` em algum site como o AST Explorer, pode-se de fato confirmar que se trata de uma atribuição. [Veja aqui.](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/2667f916f3fb99348c7e9e2e29acca1b/07c956a2f7cc164bb5f87594ef7f62e34a6a34c7)

## *Strict mode*

O código funciona no *sloppy mode* porque é válido executar atribuições à variáveis não declaradas.

Já no *strict mode* isso não é possível já que, na maioria das vezes, esse tipo de coisa provavelmente é erro do programador e idealmente deve ser tratado como erro. No modo estrito atribuições são válidas apenas a variáveis já declaradas.

## Parâmetros nomeados?

Infelizmente o JavaScript não tem argumentos nomeados com sintaxe tal como do Python.

Todavia existe uma alternativa relativamente similar. Basta utilizar objetos e a sintaxe de desestruturação. Por exemplo:

```js
// Note que a função utiliza somente um parâmetro (um objeto).
function foo({ a, b }) {
  console.log(`a is ${a}, b is ${b}`);
}

// Note que somente um argumento é fornecido (um objeto).
foo({ a: 1, b: 2 });

// A ordem pode ser alterada, a saída será a mesma.
foo({ b: 2, a: 1 });
```

Desde que essa sintaxe foi introduzida no ECMAScript 2015 tem se tornado uma prática bastante comum. Apesar disso, saiba que não se trata de argumentos nomeados. É apenas um argumento (isto é, um objeto) desestruturado.

Comment: Indo mais além, no primeiro exemplo, se fizer `foo(x=1, y=2)` funciona, pois na verdade estamos atribuindo valores às variáveis `x` e `y` e passando esses valores como argumentos para a função (se fossem parâmetros nomeados, não funcionaria). Exemplos: em JavaScript: https://ideone.com/fvqSy1 - o mesmo em Python, que possui parâmetros nomeados, não funciona: https://ideone.com/Q4ap22

Answer (score 0):

O erro apresentado não esta diretamente ligado ao fato de você passar o parâmetro e valor, e sim da declaração de variável não instanciada.

Basicamente o erro diz:

> Um valor foi atribuído a uma variável não declarada.

Mais informações: [ReferenceError: Atribuição à variável não declarada "x" - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Undeclared_var)

O simples fato de criar a variável antes, já resolve o problema, segue ex.:

```js
"use strict";

const contract = (author, socialSecurity,father, mother, year)=> {
    const statement = `I, ${author}, under the social security ${socialSecurity}, and son of ${father} and ${mother}, declare that all land after the waterfall and before the Mr. Whitaker's mills belongs to my family since ${year}.`;

    return statement;
}

var author,
    socialSecurity,
    father,
    mother,
    year;

console.log(contract(author="John Smith", socialSecurity=98989, father = "Johan Smith Bay", mother = "Mary Smith", year=1845))
```

Mas existem formas mais "bonitas e legíveis" para tal, uma vez que vc possui uma quantidade considerável de parâmetros, um objeto de parametro junto com o poder do destructuring pode ser uma boa solução:

```js
"use strict";

const contract = ({author, socialSecurity,father, mother, year}) => {
    const statement = `I, ${author}, under the social security ${socialSecurity}, and son of ${father} and ${mother}, declare that all land after the waterfall and before the Mr. Whitaker's mills belongs to my family since ${year}.`;

    return statement;
}

var contractInfo = {
    author: "John Smith",
    socialSecurity: 98989,
    father: "Johan Smith Bay",
    mother: "Mary Smith",
    year: 1845
}

console.log(contract(contractInfo));
```